# How to clone objects in typescript with typings

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, types

I am trying to extends some properties from another object:

```
interface IAlice {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
};

interface IBob extends IAlice {
  aFunction(): number;
  anotherValue: number;
};

let alice: IAlice = {
  foo: 'hi',
  bar: 'bye'
};

let bob: IBob = Object.assign({}, alice); // Typescript error no aFunction & anotherValue

bob.anotherValue = 2;
bob.aFunction = (): number => {
  return 3;
}
```

As you can see typescript returns a error.

I know a plausible workaround is to make bob values optional, but that isn't solving the problem. Or assigning values inside Object.assign doesn't work either because there's a function.

Is there anyway to let typescript recognize that the value are going to be defined?

Comment: Have you try casting ? `let bob: IBob = <IBob> Object.assign({}, alice)`;

Comment: The real question is why you want alice to be bob?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `bob` is of type `IBob` it must always have all the fields of `IBob` defined. The simplest solution is to create the object fully formed as an `IBob` instance:

```
let bob: IBob  = Object.assign({
    anotherValue: 2,
    aFunction : (): number => {
        return 3;
    }
}, alice);
```

If you want the object to be partially initialized and have some fields missing you can use `Partial`:

```
let bob: Partial<IBob> = Object.assign({}, alice);

bob.anotherValue = 2;
bob.aFunction = (): number => {
    return 3;
}
```

This will make all fields optional which might not be apropriate in all circumstances, but it's good to keep `Partial` in mind as an option.

If you really want to get fancy with your typing, you can even make just the fields of `IBob` optional while keeping the ones from `IAlice` mandatory

```
let bob: Partial<Pick<IBob, Exclude<keyof IBob, keyof IAlice>>> & IAlice = Object.assign({}, alice);

bob.anotherValue = 2;
bob.aFunction = (): number => {
    return 3;
}
```

The reason it's important to be specific about what is optional and what not is that under `strictNullChecks` you will not be able to access optional fields unless you explicitly check for null.

The brute force unsafe option is to just use a type assertion to get the assignment to work. I include this for completeness but I would avoid assertions that are not true if possible (you are basically lying to the compiler that the result of `Object.assign` has all the fields of `IBob` it does not and the compiler will miss errors that may be caused by those missing fields)

```
let bob: IBob = Object.assign({}, alice) as IBob;
// Or (but only if you are not in a tsx file)
let bob: IBob = <IBob>Object.assign({}, alice);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
let bob: IBob | IAlice = Object.assign({}, alice);
```

Now both type of objects `IBob` and `IAlice` can be assigned to `bob`.

Comment: That does not look like the desired result here, the OP is trying to create an `IBob` object not something that is either or. And with your code the next lines will not work `bob.anotherValue = 2;
bob.aFunction = (): number => {
  return 3;
}`

Comment: Schrödinger would be proud